# Java script wont find div class?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, getelementsbyclassname

```
NSString *htmlDataString = [newView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.documentElement.getElementsByClassName('field-item even')[0]"];
```

The webview called newView is being setup correctly as it works for other bits of javascript so it must be in my syntax.

The div class looks like so:

```
<div class="field-item even" property="content:encoded">
```

After break pointing htmldatastring and stepping into it, it just has the values: `@""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting element by id, but you gave it as a class in your markup. You should do:

```
<div class="field-item even" property="content:encoded">
```

Then refer in objc as:

```
NSString *htmlDataString = [newView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.documentElement.getElementById('someId')[0]"];
```

Comment: Sorry that was an old bit of code, please see my updated question, it still doesn't work. See I can't change the markup, is there anyway to get around it without markup change?

Comment: You are asking for an element having `field-item even` classname, which isn't a valid HTML attribute of course. I don't know how to pass `getElementsByClassName` two params in plain JS [in jQuery it would be trivial]. Anyway just give it an `id`, use `getElementById`, and you'll be happy.

Comment: I don't have access to the markup, but I think with a naming convention like that it uses two css classes? If its not valid markup though I will contact the web developer and issue a complaint.

Comment: Markup is valid, is just that you can't use `getElementsByClassName` with a space in the middle. Are there more `field-item` only classes **before** this one? You could just stick with `field-item` as selector.

Comment: the code before it looks like so:  <div class="content">
    <div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even" property="content:encoded"> is it possible to use that to get to that div class?

Comment: @moonwave99 It's not invalid. In fact, the order of classNames doesn't matter either. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/s5uJg/ That's working in chrome, at least.

Comment: @Shmiddty thanks your input. Why's the string returning @"" then?

Comment: I would imagine it's something to do with the binding. I'm not familiar with ios/objective c, so I can't speak from experience.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `getElementById` but if you are referring to a class so you have to use `getElementsByClassName`

```
document.documentElement.getElementsByClassName('field-item even')[0]
```

Comment: Does it work if you create an id and referring to it with getElementById?